# Weird occasional duplicate echoes in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, duplicates

This problem has got me tearing my face apart...

I have this code:

```
<?php while ($com_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_getcom)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <a href="?id=<?= $com_row['id'] ?>"><?= $com_row['name'] ?></a> 
                <?php if ($com_row['com_flag_flagged'] == 0 && $com_row['com_flag_ownerid'] == $_SESSION['sess_id']) { 
                    echo "<span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> "; 
                } ?>
                <?= $com_row['com_comment'] ?>
                <?php if ($com_row['com_auth_id'] == $_SESSION['sess_id'] || $com_row['com_stat_ownerid'] == $_SESSION['sess_id']) { ?>
                <br /><a href="?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>&delcom=<?= $com_row['com_id'] ?>"><small><font color="#b94a48">Radera</font></small></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

It prints out comments made on a "status update" as you'd see on facebook or whatever.

Now, SOMETIMES depending on which account I'm writing from it's fine but, it seems with a specific account when I comment, that comment simply is displayed twice in a row. I've checked the database and there are no duplicate entries. But somehow on certain occasions a comment is displayed twice in a row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCiJL.png
On the bottom, the comment appears twice. Strangely without the "New" label the second time...

Please help me! Why is this?

Thanks in advance!
/J

Page source code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=1">Gabbe</a> Heja          <br /><a href="?id=4&delcom=62"><small><font color="#b94a48">Radera</font></small></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=1">Gabbe</a> ee            <br /><a href="?id=4&delcom=63"><small><font color="#b94a48">Radera</font></small></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=1">Gabbe</a> aa            <br /><a href="?id=4&delcom=64"><small><font color="#b94a48">Radera</font></small></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=4">Iwar</a> <span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> Sant</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=4">Iwar</a> <span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> lol</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=2">Annelie</a> <span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> Gött :)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="?id=2">Annelie</a> Gött :)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
        <form action="profile.php?id=4" name="com_form" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="su_id" value="10" />
        <input type="hidden" name="su_authorid" value="4" />
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="com_input">Kommentar</label>
        <input type="text" name="com_input" size="45" class="form-control" id="com_input" placeholder="Skriv en kommentar...">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="com_submit" data-loading-text="Skickar..." class="btn btn-default">Skicka!</button>
        </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's more of the PHP code on the same page:

```
while ($su_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_getsu)) {
$sql_getcom = "SELECT * FROM status_comments INNER JOIN users ON id=com_auth_id INNER JOIN com_flags ON com_flag_cid=com_id WHERE com_stat_id='{$su_row['su_id']}' ORDER BY com_date ASC";
$result_getcom = mysql_query($sql_getcom); ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><table width="100%"><tr><td><?php echo "{$su_row['name']} säger: <small>({$su_row['su_date']})</small></td>"; if ($_SESSION['sess_id'] == $_GET['id']) : echo "<td align=\"right\"><a href='?del={$su_row['su_id']}'><button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></a>
</td></tr></table></h3>"; else : echo "</tr></table></h3>"; endif; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p><?php echo $su_row['su_message']; ?></p>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
<?php while ($com_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_getcom)) { ?>
         <tr>
            <td class="<?= $com_row['com_id'] ?>"><a href="?id=<?= $com_row['id'] ?>"><?= $com_row['name'] ?></a> <?php if ($com_row['com_flag_flagged'] == 0 && $com_row['com_flag_ownerid'] == $_SESSION['sess_id']) { echo "<span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> "; } ?><?= $com_row['com_comment'] ?>
<?php if ($com_row['com_auth_id'] == $_SESSION['sess_id'] || $com_row['com_stat_ownerid'] == $_SESSION['sess_id']) { ?>
            <br /><a href="?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>&delcom=<?= $com_row['com_id'] ?>"><small><font color="#b94a48">Radera</font></small></a><?php } ?></td>
         </tr>
<?php } ?>
         <tr>
            <td>
            <form action="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" name="com_form" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="su_id" value="<?= $su_row['su_id'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="su_authorid" value="<?= $su_row['su_auth_id'] ?>" />
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="com_input">Kommentar</label>
            <input type="text" name="com_input" size="45" class="form-control" id="com_input" placeholder="Skriv en kommentar...">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="com_submit" data-loading-text="Skickar..." class="btn btn-default">Skicka!</button>
            </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Edit for Chris:
Thank you, but none of those solutions will work out for what I'm trying to do. I will explain the com_flags as simply as I can.

com_flags: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88cko.png

Com_flag_id is just a unique id for that specific flag, com_flag_cid is referring to the id of the comment (com_id) that the flag is put on. com_flag_ownerid is referring to the user id that "owns" that flag and lastly, com_flag_flagged is 0 if the comment is unread or unseen, I will later program it to change to 1 as soon as the user in question has seen that comment.

Now, the flags are there to keep track of what comment is NEW for a specific user. If someone writes a comment on another users status update, the author of that status update will recieve a flag in com_flags with the information about that comment. If that user then posts a comment on his own status update again, the other person will recieve a flag letting him know there's been a comment on a status update that he's already commented on, you see? So, if there's 10 different people all commenting on one status update, they will all recieve flags as soon as another user comments that status update.

I THINK I've got the part of adding flags down correctly, here's the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['com_submit'])) {
    $_POST = db_escape($_POST);

    if (empty($_POST['com_input'])) {
        $sus = "<br /><div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i> Fältet var tomt.</div>";
    } else {
    $_POST['com_input'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['com_input']);
    $sql_com = "INSERT INTO status_comments(com_stat_id,com_stat_ownerid,com_auth_id,com_comment) VALUES('{$_POST['su_id']}', '{$_POST['su_authorid']}', '{$_SESSION['sess_id']}', '{$_POST['com_input']}')";
    $result_com = mysql_query($sql_com);
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
    $lastrow = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $lastInsertId = $lastrow[0];

    $sql_commentors = "SELECT DISTINCT com_auth_id FROM status_comments WHERE com_stat_id='{$_POST['su_id']}' AND (com_auth_id!='{$_SESSION['sess_id']}' AND com_auth_id!='{$_POST['su_authorid']}')";
    $result_commentors = mysql_query($sql_commentors);
    $num_commentors = mysql_num_rows($result_commentors);

    if ($_POST['su_authorid'] != $_SESSION['sess_id']) {
    $sql_comflags = "INSERT INTO com_flags(com_flag_cid,com_flag_ownerid) VALUES('{$lastInsertId}', '{$_POST['su_authorid']}')";
    $result_comflags = mysql_query($sql_comflags);
    if ($num_commentors > 0) {
    while ($listcoms = mysql_fetch_array($result_commentors)) {
        $sql_comflags2 = "INSERT INTO com_flags(com_flag_cid,com_flag_ownerid) VALUES('{$lastInsertId}', '{$listcoms['com_auth_id']}')";
        $result_comflags2 = mysql_query($sql_comflags2);
    }
    }
    header("Location: ?id={$_GET['id']}&coms=");
    } else {
    if ($num_commentors > 0) {
    while ($listcoms = mysql_fetch_array($result_commentors)) {
        $sql_comflags = "INSERT INTO com_flags(com_flag_cid,com_flag_ownerid) VALUES('{$lastInsertId}', '{$listcoms['com_auth_id']}')";
        $result_comflags = mysql_query($sql_comflags);
    }
    }
    header("Location: ?id={$_GET['id']}&coms=");
    }
    }
}
```

Final edit (hopefully):

I made a new SELECT:

```
$sql_getflags = "SELECT * FROM com_flags WHERE com_flag_cid='{$com_row['com_id']}' AND com_flag_ownerid='{$_SESSION['sess_id']}'";
$result_getflags = mysql_query($sql_getflags);
```

and I put this inside the while for each comment:

```
while ($flags_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_getflags)) { if ($flags_row['com_flag_flagged'] == 0 && $flags_row['com_flag_ownerid'] == $_SESSION['sess_id']) { echo "<span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> "; } }
```

That seemed to fix it right up! Do you understand what I was trying to do? And if so, do you think this is a final solution? Oh, and of course, thank you a thousand times for your help, Chris. You're GOLD.

Comment: Did you update the overall comment select and remove that join condition? If so, I think you are good to go!

Comment: Yes! That SELECT is now: `$sql_getcom = "SELECT * FROM status_comments INNER JOIN users ON id=com_auth_id WHERE com_stat_id='{$su_row['su_id']}' ORDER BY com_date ASC";`

I've added the flag support and even now programmed the notifications to work accordingly, so I'm all done with this whole function. THE RELIEF!!

Once again, @ChrisRasco I have to say thank you SO much. I most likely wouldn't have been able to do this without your help. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, here is the obligatory reminder that the mysql* functions are now deprecated and you should move to PDO or mysqli.

Next, mysql_fetch_array() can return either numerically indexed arrays or associative arrays depending on how you use it. Your use suggests you may want to use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead.

Lastly, when the duplicate comment appears, is it just the comment body or is it the entire  code structure that appears?

UPDATE: SQL Issue

When we look at the query that pulls all of your comments (and associated table data) we have this query/line:

```
$sql_getcom = "SELECT * FROM status_comments INNER JOIN users ON id=com_auth_id INNER JOIN com_flags ON com_flag_cid=com_id WHERE com_stat_id='{$su_row['su_id']}' ORDER BY com_date ASC";
```

status_comments is the table containing each comment. We do an inner join to the users table, which pulls in the comment author information based on status_comments.com_auth_id. Next, we do an inner join on the com_flags table. I'm not entirely clear what we use the flags for in this context, but that's not important. The reason you see 2 entries for comment 67 is that the inner join returns 2 rows since there are 2 entries in the com_flags table for it (com_flags.com_flag_id 49 and 50). Your code assumes a 1:1 relationship here and doesn't account for the fact that there are 2 flags.

You've got 2 ways to solve this:

1. You can set a variable before your loop that tracks the current comment and if the current comment appears twice, you'll skip the 2nd one. The downside is this invalidates whatever use you have for the 2nd flag on that comment and will produce inconsistencies since sometimes 49 may be first and sometimes 50 will be first.
2. You can ditch the 2nd flag and guarantee there is a 1:1 relationship between flags and comments and no code changes are required.

Here's some code for the first solution. You'll have to set the correct variable names and merge it with your existing code.

```
$current_comment = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    if($current_comment != $row['comment_id']) // This is a new comment
    {
        $current_comment = $row['comment_id']; // Set our new one to the current
        echo "Print out some stuff, like our comment";
    }
    // else - not needed - but this means we are processing the same comment as last time so we skip it
}
```

Comment: Duly noted! I'm just using mysql because I'm used to it and this project is local, not public. I will look into switching to mysqli though, thanks!

In reply to the fetch_assoc stuff: Why should I use that instead and what is the difference?

I'll show you in a screenshot:
http://i.imgur.com/ud27j6v.png

On the bottom, the comment appears twice. Strangely without the "New" label the second time...

Comment: The way you are referencing the data in the row, $com_row['field_name'] is the associative way. A numerical index would be $com_row[0]. mysql_fetch_array() can do both, but you have to tell it which way you want the data back. Since you are already using the associative way, it makes sense to use that method. As for the duplicate, can you view the source of the page and post that?

Comment: I see! Thanks for clearing that up for me. I will start using mysql_fetch_assoc instead when referencing row names.

Yes, certainly. I will post the table's source code in my first post for viewing pleasure!

Comment: And of course, if there's any other type of information you need, just let me know and I will get it for you.

Comment: Based on the above code, I'm not seeing any reasons for the duplicate. You could try adding a class="comment_id" part to the surrounding <td> tag just to ensure these aren't duplicates.

Comment: Well, I still get: `<tr>
   <td class="65"><a href="?id=4">Iwar</a> <span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> Sant</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="66"><a href="?id=4">Iwar</a> <span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> lol</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="67"><a href="?id=2">Annelie</a> <span class='label label-default'>Nytt!</span> Gött :)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="67"><a href="?id=2">Annelie</a> Gött :)</td>
   </tr>` So I don't know. I will add more of the code to my original post, maybe it'll help you!

Comment: Please, don't give up on me though. There's got to be a valid reason for this. Just let me know if you'd like more of the code or something else you might need to figure this out with me.

Comment: Looking at your query, is it possible for a comment to have more than 1 corresponding entry in the com_flags table?

Comment: Yes, I think you might be on to something there!
Look at this screen of the table com_flags: http://i.imgur.com/NijIP4j.png

Now, I'm VERY tired and have been programming all night. It's 08:00 AM now and I'm just tired and confused. By looking at the query and that screen of com_flags; Can you see a problem? And if so, please help me on how to patch that up. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Ah, as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/nXu4aUZ.png

It's possible that the SELECT is somehow selecting the last comment there twice, if you look at the previous screen of com_flags and how there's 2 entries regarding id #67 which is that last post. I just have no idea on how to fix this. But hopefully you do :)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my original post with more information.

Comment: So if the com_flags table will always potentially have more than 1 entry for a given table you've got 2 choices (again). First, you can strip out that join and fetch the flags with a separate query within the loop reducing the number of records for each comment to 1. Second, you can implement the logic that tracks the comment and bypasses the additional records (whose only change is the flag data that we joined on).

Comment: Oh my lord, I think I finally figured it out, my friend! Check my original post please! I updated it.